# What method is called when using a BottomNavigationBar in flutter. I have code in the Init State that is not being called

Tags: flutter

When I switch from one tab to another tab on my application the init tab is not being called. What method would be the proper method to call when the index is switched?

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('ConnectU'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
              child: new Text('Logout',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: signOut)
        ],
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex], // new
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped, // new
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.blueGrey[200],// new
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            title: Text('Search'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('Add'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
            title: Text('Messages'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('Profile')
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is my code for the navigation bar.

```
class homeIndexState extends State<playerHomePageIndex> {
  List<Post> postList;

  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: showTodoList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_checkEmailVerification();
    postList = new List();

    postList.clear();
    popList();

  }
```

This is the init state I am attempting to call. What method should I expect to be called instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `didUpdateWidget` insted of `initState`, since `initState` is only called one and one time only before the first render, and `didUpdateWidget` gets called whenever `setState` is called